# In the English version of Citadels, what is the action text on the card named Armory/Weaponry?

Tags: citadels

I happen to have a Bulgarian version that does not specify if the player can destroy 1 enemy building, while sacrificing it, or the whole city. It's hard to explain, but I think it was translated by someone unfamiliar with the exact Bulgarian meaning.

What does the English version of the card say?

Answer (score 5):

From [this thread](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/98116/armory-card) on BoardGameGeek, someone posts:

> The card says:
>   During your turn, you may destroy the Armory in order to destroy any other district card of your choice in another player's city.

The [Wikipedia page for Citadels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citadels_%28card_game%29) refers back to that thread.

Later in the thread, the game designer (Bruno Faidutti) mentions that the ability to destroy one district can be used when a player builds an eighth district (which would end the game at the end of that round), even though normally you can't destroy a district in a city that's already completed.

> BF: I admit the rules are ambiguous on this, but my idea was that it is allowed.
>   Q: Would the game still end, as the card says the game ends after the turn, even though the condition is no longer met?
>   BF: Yes, it would.